# Grails errors in connecting to sms plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, vonage

First two files are the 'SmsController.groovy' and 'applicationContext.xml' which I think cause the errors.

**'SmsController.groovy':**

```
package nexmo

import grails.plugin.nexmo.NexmoException

class SmsControllerController {

// Inject the service
def nexmoService
def smsResult

def index() {

    try {
        // Send the message "What's up?" to 1-500-123-4567

        smsResult = nexmoService.sendSms("61451062006", "What's up?")
    }

        catch (NexmoException e) {
            // Handle error if failure
        }
    }
}
```

**'applicationContext.xml':**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
    <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
    <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
</bean>

<bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
    <property name="encoding">
        <value>utf-8</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

**The below are the errors I'm getting after copying the files from new apps. (applicationContext.xml, sitemesh.xml & some .tld files):**

```
context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; ne
sted exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: nexmo.SmsController
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: nexmo.SmsController
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nexmo.SmsController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
context.GrailsContextLoaderListener Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init me
thod failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: nexmo.SmsController
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; ne
sted exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: nexmo.SmsController
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: nexmo.SmsController
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nexmo.SmsController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably due to a mismatch between the package and the directory the file is in. If the controller is in `grails-app/controllers/nexmo/SmsController.groovy`, you need the corresponding package statement:

```
package nexmo

class SmsController {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I was able to go to 'http://localhost:8080/nexmo'. However, it displays like this: HTTP Status 404 - "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/index.gsp" not found.

Comment: This is like an onion, each layer you peel off reveals more underneath. Does `grails-app/views/index.gsp` exist? If not, create it. Like before, you can get the default file that's created for new apps by creating a new app with the same version of Grails and copying it from there. I assume you're going to continue to have problems like this, since it looks like a lot of important files have been removed. You should probably create a new app and copy the code and files that are related to Nexmo into it, rather than fixing all of these artificial problems one at a time.

Comment: There was no index.gsp so I put it in there. After that, I also put index.gsp in sms/index.gsp. It displays again: 'HTTP Status 404 - "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/sms/index.gsp" not found.'